# how to use fscanf to read 7th character in array

Tags: arrays, character, scanf

I have a file with data as so:

7/17/2014   10982.73    11011.93    10879.67    10890.44    3381680000  10890.44

I want to read only the very last value in the array, for example 10890.44, then print it out.

The below code works fine if the first values (ex. 7/17/2014) isn't in the file:

```
while(!feof(file_read))
{
fscanf(file_read, "%f %f %f %f %ld %f", &d1, &d2, &d3, &d4, &d5, &d6);
fprintf(file_write, "%f\n", d6);
}
```

However, as soon as it sees the '/' character my code explodes into an ever expanding output file. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think u should use string type for date and that should solve your problem